# grepl for a period "." in R?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

Lets say I have a string "Hello." I want to see if this string contains a period:

```
text <- "Hello."
results <- grepl(".", text)
```

This returns results as TRUE, but it would return that as well if text is `"Hello"` without the period.

I'm confused, I can't find anything about this in the documentation and it only does this for the period.

Any ideas?

Comment: `"."` is *any* character. ***Anything***. You meant `"\\."`.

Comment: Au contraire! The documentation spends an enormous amount of time describing how `grepl` uses regular expressions, in which `.` is a special character. There are even link in the documentation to the sections on regular expressions, and much discussion of how setting `fixed = TRUE` will perform exact matching, not using regular expressions.

Comment: Spot on. @joran, I'll need to comb through it, because I don't see it in the Pattern Matchin and Replacement text.

Comment: @marc under the very first argument `pattern` it says `character string containing a regular expression` where *regular expression* is a link to the page on regular expressions where this information is sensibly contained! :-)

Comment: @SimonO101: huge help! Thanks.

Comment: In marc's defense, I too once found it quite confusing that `?regexpr` does not itself document regular expression matching rules, and that what one really needs is `?regex`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See the differences with these examples

```
 > grepl("\\.", "Hello.")
[1] TRUE
> grepl("\\.", "Hello")
[1] FALSE
```

the `.` means anything as pointed out by SimonO101, if you want to look for an explicit `.` then you have to skip it by using `\\.` which means look for a `.`

R documentation is extensive on regular expressions, you can also take a look at [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) to understand the use of the dot.

Comment: Does ´\\´ affect the subsequent character (in this case, the dot), or is there a way to make it encompass a number of subsequent characters? Let's say I don't want to write ´\\.\\.\\.´ to match ´"..."´. Can I do ´\\(.)´ or something like that?

Comment: @Fabian Habersack For you to capture one or more dots (.), you have to use the quantifier `+`, so you can write `\\.+`

Comment: Okay, but what if I need to match either a specific amount of dots which let's say equaly 10 or what if I want to match 10+ times a dot? Can I do `\\.{10}` ? Plus, how would I match "10 or more"?

Comment: @FabianHabersack you can read some basic regex rules [here](https://regexone.com/lesson/repeating_characters)

Comment: Why `\\.` not conventional escape `\.` ?

Comment: for 3 consecuttive dots `...` we use `\\.\\.\\.` other wise it would confuse with dots interspersed with other characters.

Answer (score 16):

I use Jilber's approach usually but here are two other ways:

```
> grepl("[.]", "Hello.")
[1] TRUE
> grepl("[.]", "Hello")
[1] FALSE

> grepl(".", "Hello.", fixed = TRUE)
[1] TRUE
> grepl(".", "Hello", fixed = TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```